# Incorrect technique or signal chain noise?

Tags: guitar, recording, logic-pro, noise

I am getting a "hiss" noise from my amp sim after I play a note. This is not present in low gain. But gets pretty audible on higher gain. My signal chain is a guitar, interface, Logic pro with a toneforge amp sim (the noise was present in other amp sims too). I tried changing the guitar, cable and the interface. But it did not change a thing. The noise gate is already at a high level. Increasing it anymore starts to clip my sound. I have attached a link to a clip i recorded with palm mutes. Could this be because of wrong right hand technique? If so, how can I improve? If not, how can i remove this noise?

[Drive link to audio clip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qhu-XBzDjs7T-NC2s5xBgmTfzoYlpX8v)

Comment: I can't hear a problem with your sample. Sounds very clean to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a fairly normal level of noise for a high-gain sound. That's the reason these amp sims have noise gates built into them - high-gain means you amplify all sorts of noise along with the signal, from sources both external (the power grid, radio, various electronic devices) and internal (thermal noise in the pickup and electronics).

As far as technique is concerned: of course you have to mute all other strings while playing muted rhythm stuff, but it doesn't sound like your hiss is caused by resonating strings, so you're probably doing the right things here.

Regarding the signal chain, there are things you can try:

1. Most importantly, use a humbucker instead of a single coil, but it sounds like you're doing that already.
2. Keep your guitar at a distance (more than 1m) from the computer and other electronic devices, put your cell phone in flight mode.
3. Check if the electronics cavity of your guitar is shielded. If not, and if you're willing to tinker with it, search on Youtube for "guitar shielding".
4. Try different cables.

If none of that helps, learn to live with it, and see if you can still even perceive it in a mix, with bass and vocals and cymbals and everything. You're playing high-gain guitar - it doesn't have to be squeaky clean.

Comment: OK. I was worried because this noise was not present when doing nothing. It comes up right after I pick. Will check the other parameters u specified.